# Hiding Status Bar / White Bar At Top of Windows 10 Universal App on Phone

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

How do I get rid of the white bar at the top of a Windows 10 for phone app?

Nick.

Comment: A similar question has already been asked.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594625/windows-10-mobile-cannot-hide-status-bar-statusbar-doesnt-exist-in-context

Comment: That was posted July 23rd 2015, this was posted May 15 2015, this was asked first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick answer: Don't do anything. This will be fixed in a future build.

Long answer: when you do File>New to create a new VB/C# UWP app, by default its App.xaml sets RequestedTheme="Light". This causes the background of the statusbar to be white. It should also cause the foreground of the statusbar to be black, but this isn't happening at the moment in Win10.Mobile build 10080... instead it's picking up the foreground color from the user's own "light-theme vs dark-theme" preferences.

As a workaround for now, you could set RequestedTheme="Default". (You can't set RequestedTheme="Dark" since that will have the opposite problem for folks who picked a light theme for their phones!)

Another workaround for now is to control the statusbar colors explicitly yourself:

```
StatusBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.White
StatusBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.Black
StatusBar.BackgroundOpacity = 1
```

Comment: Using the second workaround requires adding a reference to "Microsoft Mobile Extension SDK for Universal App Platform"

Comment: This still happens as of november 2016 ;)