# HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken API changed in Windows 10

Tags: uuid, windows-store, windows-10

I'm using HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken in my app. See following resource:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/JJ553431.aspx

Now, Windows.System.Profile is no longer available in the new Windows SDK 10240. Any idea where I can find it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's available for device family "Desktop" and "Mobile" only. (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx )

So you have to add an Extension SDK. You can do this using the Reference Manager.
See the detailed description how to add an Extension SDK here:
[Windows 10 Mobile - cannot hide status bar (StatusBar doesn't exist in context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594625/windows-10-mobile-cannot-hide-status-bar-statusbar-doesnt-exist-in-context/31604391#31604391)

Comment: Thanks, I had found this, too. Is it just me, or is microsoft's documentation cryptic and/or non-existent?

Comment: To be overly clear, the extension to include is apparently the aptly named [Windows.Desktop.Extensions for the UWP](http://imgur.com/CKd46MB), at least for the Desktop, natch. ;^)